# Device not booting and not allowed me to unlock boot loader

Tags: htc-desire

Everytime I try to boot the device HTC Desire 728 I am getting a white screen with

```
*** Software status: Modified ***
*** Locked ***
HTC_AS0CML 128 SHIP S-ON
*** Security Warning ***
CID-HTC__J15
LK-1.01.0000
OS-1.36.401.4


VOL Up to previous item
VOL Down to next item
Power Key to select item

REBOOT
REBOOT TO BOOT-LOADER
BOOT TO DOWNLOAD MODE
BOOT TO RECOVERY MODE
POWER DOWN
```

Tried Booting into recovery and selecting "wipe data and factory reset" but still the same problem.

Tried to `fastboot boot ..` but it says

```
FAILED (remote: 'download for partition 'unlocktoken' is not allowed')
fastboot: error: Command failed
```

I searched the web and found that I must first unlock bootloader (see [this link](https://www.htcdev.com/bootloader/unlock-instructions/)) **But however my device is locked and I cannot even boot it to enable "Developer Mode" and "Enable OEM Unlock" options from settings.**

Can you suggest what to do?

Comment: this is called a brick. fastboot not working on locked bootloader. find another way to flash official ROM

Comment: https://androidmtk.com/flash-stock-rom-using-smart-phone-flash-tool

Comment: not compatible with SP Flash Tool but you can create scatter file and try to convert 
(haven't downloaded so can't really say what format it is) https://www.leakite.com/htc-desire-728-official-firmware-flash-file